# Type GQLSchema is not assignable to type undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

Okay... I am [trying to develop](https://github.com/maramal/gqlhttptools) a GraphQL solution to attach several type definitions to [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql) `graphqlHTTP()` `typeDef` property without worrying about creating a single schema for each type or nesting strings.

My issue here is whenever I pass an array of arguments to function `createSchema()` it displays an error on the second item of the array (yes, not in the first):
[image: Error]
***Note:** Not sure if the second problem is an actual error or just a warning. I guess it is warning.*

So, this is the function itself:

```js
  static createSchema(typeDefs: GQLSchema | [GQLSchema]): string {
    let schema = '';

    if (Array.isArray(typeDefs)) {
      typeDefs.forEach((typeDef) => {
        schema += GQLHTTPTools.addSchema(typeDef);
      });
    } else {
      schema = GQLHTTPTools.addSchema(typeDefs);
    }

    return schema;
  }

  // just in case:
  private static addSchema(typeDef: GQLSchema): string {
    const { types } = typeDef;
    let schema = '';

    if (types.Query !== undefined) {
      schema += `type Query {\n\t${types.Query}\n}\n`;
      delete types.Query;
    }
    if (types.Mutation !== undefined) {
      schema += `type Mutation {\n\t${types.Mutation}\n}\n`;
      delete types.Mutation;
    }
    if (types.Custom !== undefined) {
      schema += types.Custom.map((type) => {
        const key = Object.keys(type)[0];
        const val = Object.values(type)[0];
        return `type ${key} {\n\t${val}\n}`;
      });
    }

    return schema;
  }
```

Not sure if it's important, but this is the `GQLSchema` class definition:

```js
export default class GQLSchema {
  constructor(public totalTypes: number, public totalCustomTypes: number, public types: GQLType) {}
}
```

If I do pass a single `GQLSchema` object it works... but not if I use a `GQLSchema` array. Not sure why isn't working. Any clues?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? What line is the error occurring on exactly?

Comment: I added the line in the image, is 41, my bad.

Comment: Apart from the tuple-vs-array issue, you should not use `GQLSchema` as a type when you are actually dealing with strings. Although, the actual root issue is working with strings in the first place - any graphql library should be working with objects. Or are you trying to re-invent [`printSchema`](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printschema)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript `[X]` is a [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)

> Tuple types allow you to express an array with a fixed number of elements whose types are known, but need not be the same.

So `[X]` means an array with a length of exactly one where the first element is of the type `X`. `[X, Y]` means an array with a length of exactly two where the first element is of type `X` and the second element is of type `Y`. And so on.

If your intent is to type an array of any length where every element is a specific type, use an [Array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) instead: `X[]` or `Array<X>` (these are equivalent).

Comment: In fact, the second error was generated because of a typing mistake, but it really helped me to understand the first one. Thank you.